# Let $\phi$ satisfy $\phi(x)=f(x)+\int_0^x\sin(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt$. Then $\phi$ is given by?

Tags: integral-equations

Let $\phi$ satisfy,

$$\phi(x)=f(x)+\int_0^x\sin(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt$$

Then $\phi$ is given by,

1. $\phi(x)=f(x)+\int_0^x(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt$
2. $\phi(x)=f(x)+\int_0^x\sin(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt$
3. $\phi(x)=f(x)+\int_0^x\cos(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt$
4. $\phi(x)=f(x)-\int_0^x\sin(x-t)\phi(t)\,dt$

This question is already asked but I am not clear with that answer and I am a new contributor to stack exchange so I don't have 50 ruputations to post comment in that place.  so can anyone please tell me how to solve this...I tried but I get $\phi''(x)=f''(x)$

Comment: If you have a question about a previous Q&A then it would be helpful to add a *link* to that question, and explain your doubts about the answer.

Comment: ss a start differentiate all equations by $x$ then sub in 1 to 5 to see what works.

Comment: Are you sure the options are correct?

Comment: (2) and (4) are the same?

Comment: I am extremely sorry ...Now I edited the options

Comment: Now the options are correct

Comment: In the current version of the question, isn't (2) exactly the given equation?

Comment: yes the option 2 is given eqn

Comment: What is the point of the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which of the following satisfies the equation $\phi(x)=f(x)+\int_{0}^{x}\sin(x-t)\phi(t)dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217239/which-of-the-following-satisfies-the-equation-phix-fx-int-0x-sinx-t)

Answer (score 2):

You have$$\phi(x)=f(x)+\sin(x)*\phi(x)$$Let the Laplace transform of $\phi(t),\mathcal L[\phi(t)]=H(s)$ and that of $f(t)$ be $F(s)$. Take the Laplace transform of both sides:$$H(s)=F(s)+\frac{H(s)}{s^2+1}\\\implies H(s)=\left(1+\frac1{s^2}\right)F(s)$$Taking the inverse Laplace transform,$$\phi(t)=f(t)+\int_0^t(t-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau,t\ge0$$You can also write$$\phi(t)=f(t)+\int_0^tf(t-\tau)\tau~d\tau,t\ge0$$

Comment: Sorry sir...Can you please explain the problem without using laplace transform